# how to scrape data from google map of particular website

Tags: javascript, php

i'm scraping google map data from a website.try to use javascript and php, but i read on google  JavaScript can not read other domains, you are not going to scrape with JavaScript. If they do not have an api, than JavaScript is not going to help

i want to make a script which goes to a particular point of google map on search and scrape data from that point

thanks in advance
regards

Comment: What data you want to scrap?

Comment: @ultra similar to the google map displayed in this site http://canada.cbsoutdoor.com/en/locations/..i hope you understand my question

Comment: No I don't - please provide working link and description of data you are looking for.

Comment: @Ultra as you will see some star in google map onclick,popbox will generate ,onclick particular point say Posters then another mark will appear. onclick they produce some information i want to fetch that information.link http://canada.cbsoutdoor.com/en/locations/

Comment: Reformat your question to be clear and I can +1 as I was trying to solve that as well. As far as I can tell you CAN use API for it but need to disguise as domain by JavaScript console (inject yourself into iframe window object).